# PHP comparison operator not working in MySQL streak query

Tags: php, mysql, operators

In attempting to calculate the longest goalscoring streak for a single player, I've hit a stumbling block with the `>=` PHP operator not performing as intended.

The data is presented in a table as follows:

```
     date         gls   
------------------------
  1980-08-16       2   
  1980-08-19       1  
  1980-08-23       1
  1980-08-26       0
  1980-08-30       1
  1980-09-06       2
  1980-09-13       0
... and so on
```

The PHP query I am using is as follows:

```
SELECT gls, MIN(date) as StartDate, MAX(date) as EndDate, COUNT(*) as Games 
FROM (SELECT gls, date, 
            (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                FROM goalsengine G 
                WHERE G.gls <> GE.gls
                AND G.date <= GE.date) as RunGroup
    FROM goalsengine GE) A 
WHERE gls>='1' 
GROUP BY gls, RunGroup 
ORDER BY Games
```

I formed the query this way in the belief that `>=` would tally up streaks where this player had scored one or more goals in a game. From the table above, the first three entries would represent a scoring run of three games, for example.

Instead, the query is returning streaks but only where a certain number of goals are scored i.e. despite scoring in the first three games, the first entry (where two goals were scored, not one) is ignored when the streak is returned.

To return the results, I am using the following:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  
{
 {$startrundate = date("d F Y",strtotime($row['StartDate']));}
 {$endrundate = date("d F Y",strtotime($row['EndDate']));}          
echo "<tr>";   
echo "<td>".$row['Games']."</td>";
echo "<td class='tableprofile' style='text-align:right;'>".$startrundate." - ".$endrundate."</td>";  
echo "</tr>";    
$rowCount += 1;
}
```

By comparison, `WHERE gls='0'` is giving me the desired non-goalscoring streaks. I feel I have perhaps overlooked something straightforward but cannot see what.

Comment: Only a suggestion, but have you considered using HAVING after the GROUP BY to filter your 'gls'.. Something like `GROUP BY gls, RunGroup HAVING gls >= 1 ORDER BY Games`

Comment: Where is the PHP code you're asking about?

Comment: I hadn't considered that @MaggsWeb, but it hasn't made a difference to the output.

Comment: @Barmar, I've amended the question with further details if that's what you were referring to?

Comment: I guess the last row should be 1980-09-13 and not 1980-08-13, so the date is continously growing

Comment: Yes @LeifNeland, apologies for that oversight

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to work out a solution to this particular issue and it works as far as I can tell, having counted some of the raw data out manually.

```
SELECT gls, MIN(date) as StartDate, MAX(date) as EndDate, COUNT(*) as Games 
FROM (SELECT gls, date, 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM goalsengine G  
            WHERE IF(G.gls IN ('1','2','3','4','5'),1,0) <> IF(GE.gls IN ('1','2','3','4','5'),1,0)
    AND G.date <= GE.date) as RunGroup
    FROM goalsengine GE) A 
WHERE gls IN ('1','2','3','4','5') GROUP BY IF(bg IN ('1','2','3','4','5'),1,0), RunGroup ORDER BY Games DESC LIMIT 3");
```

I admit it's not exactly pretty, but it's doing the job for now. I have gone to 5 in the calculation as that's the maximum number of goals scored in a single match with regards to this data set.